# How to Read Message From mail.tm by c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

how can get message from mail.tm
i have api can create email and can get token to sign in in website but when make api to get message it didn't get

```
HttpWebRequest hwq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mail.tm/messages?page=1");
        hwq.Method = "GET";
        hwq.Accept = "application/ld+json";
        hwq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer "+"Token");
        var res = hwq.GetResponse();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            dynamic dd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

it run but get empty like it

```
{{"@context": "/contexts/Message","@id": "/messages",  "@type": "hydra:Collection","hydra:member": [],"hydra:totalItems": 0}}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the .NET library they recommend. It's linked under [Integrations](https://docs.mail.tm/#integrations).

Comment: thanks a have used it but i want know why it get empty in my code

Answer (score 0):

this code run in first code i send header "Bearer" then Token but i must send header like "Bearer " + "Token"
i must send it with space after "Bearer" then Token

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        HttpWebRequest hwq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mail.tm/messages?page=1");
        hwq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + "Token");
        hwq.Method = "GET";
        hwq.Accept = "application/json";
        var res = hwq.GetResponse();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string a1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.